# SseEmitter Spring MVC returnning transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a SpringMVC project in which i am using SseEmitter in one of my REST controller. 
Below is the code :

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/finite/{count}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public SseEmitter getFiniteMessages(@PathVariable int count){
    LOG.info("Request received for finite messages.");
    final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.execute(() -> {
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        try {
          emitter.send(LocalTime.now().toString() , MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
          Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          LOG.error(e.getMessage());
          emitter.completeWithError(e);
          return;
        }
      }
      emitter.complete();
    });

    return emitter;
  }
```

But when i am doing curl to it i.e.

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/score/sse/finite/4
```

i am getting

> curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

I am not able to figure out where is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue.
I have added the below tag in web.xml file.

```
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

This allows the Servlet to store incoming requests for later response, like for my use for sending Server Sent Event.

Here is the complete servlet mapping.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>score</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
```